# How to i get the imported text file to print its information on the same line?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, import

```
def main():
    numbers = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
    lines = numbers.readline()
    while lines != '':
        print (lines, end='')
        lines = numbers.readline()
    numbers.close()

main()
```

output

```
    = RESTART: /Users/jasonbonvie/Desktop/python class /Chapter 6 /program64.py =
13
11
9
9
5
19
9
```

I would like all those numbers to be on the same line with a space between them i cant figure it out please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(lines.rstrip('\n'), end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.readline()` *includes* the line terminator in its return value, so `end=''` will not suppress the usual new line.

You can use `string.rstrip()` to help here:

```
def main():
    with open('numbers.txt') as numbers:
    for line in numbers:
        print(lines.rstrip(), end='')
    numbers.close()
```

Note the use of `with` to automatically and properly handle file closure, and iterating of the file object in a `for` loop to process each line from the file.

Also, you might need to be specific about the characters that you are stripping off the end of each line: `string.rstrip()` will remove *all* whitespace characters at the end of the line. If your data has whitespace at the end of the line, and you want to preserve that whitespace, you can explicitly specify the character(s) to strip.